# 500 error in Laravel but log folder is empty

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in a Client's Laravel project which version is 5.7.28. But I am not getting anything in `storage/logs/` folder. I copied the `.env.example` to `.env`. I run `composer install` and `php artisan key:generate`. Some of my `.env` files configuration is like below

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:8ovbzfpWGsGTDyDIRWDO8VKObeXGyWqnMVw5KjTVJTc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

I set permission 777 for all folders.

But I am getting `500` error. How can I solve the error.

Comment: Can you show that error? Maybe the error comes from the server, not Laravel. Sometimes it's an .htaccess issue

Comment: Thanks @SangNguyen, I could not catch the error.I am getting 500 in browser. How can I solve the issue ? Thanks.

Comment: You can remove .htaccess file then try again. And I think you shouldn't chmod all folders 777, some servers don't accept that.

Comment: Thanks @SangNguyen I am using localhost.

Comment: If you're running your app using `php artisan serve`, you need to restart it.

Comment: run `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Thanks @Hamelraj, I am getting this error ` Predis\Connection\ConnectionException  : Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
`. Thanks.

Comment: i think you using redis so check your connection is correct using this https://rapidsol.blogspot.com/2018/10/php-fatal-error-uncaught.html

Comment: Thanks @Hamelraj, I don't know how to use redis. Can I avoid redis for this time ?

Comment: juts try im not sure man ..... :)

Answer (score 1):

try change to prod mode: `APP_ENV=production` then back to dev mode

don't forget to run: `php artisan config:clear` -> `php artisan env`

Comment: Thanks @Khaled Alam. `try change to prod mode: APP_ENV=production then back to dev mode` What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Run
php artisan optimize 
Before production

Comment: Thanks @Juyel Rana. I am getting this result.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKO30.png

Comment: Has your problem solved? If not solved check your .env file DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD correctly put or not.

Comment: comment out bellow code from your api.php    =>                                                                                                                                     Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});